# The SaveChanges is not getting reflected in the raven database

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am very new to RavenDB.

When I call `SaveChanges()` on my session it executes successfully but the data is not getting stored in the DB.

My code is as follows:

```
using (var session = RavenDocumentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var time = session.Query<Exampleusers>()
            .Where(x => x.Username == userName).FirstOrDefault();
    var temp = time.Id;
    var data = session.Load<Exampleusers>(
            string.Format("Exampleusers/{0}", temp));

    data.Expiration = DateTime.Now;

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

What is causing the problem?

Comment: How do you know that the data is not getting saved? Have you checked with Raven Studio? Can you post how do you try to read back the saved data?

Comment: Yes i checked in the raven studio , With help of raven studio only i was able to find out that the data is not getting saved

Comment: SaveChnages() , saveChnages() or SaveChanges() or what exactly?  I was going to change/edit the post but wanted to make sure.

Comment: Sorry about that its "SaveChanges()"

Comment: Can it be that the stale indexes tricks you? Try to execute your save code wait a 20-30 seconds then check it again with raven studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading the Exampleusers pass in temp and not string.format(...)

```
using (var session = RavenDocumentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var time = session.Query<Exampleusers>()
        .Where(x => x.Username == userName).FirstOrDefault();
    var temp = time.Id;
    var data = session.Load<Exampleusers>(temp);

    data.Expiration = DateTime.Now;
    session.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: Thank u all for helping out :) .

Comment: No - you don't need to call `session.Store(data)`.  It is already tracked.  That would be redundant.

Comment: [Reference here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/basic-operations/loading-editing-existing-document) about half way down, "You don't have to call an Update method, or track any changes yourself. RavenDB will do all of that for you."

Comment: Thanks for the reference Matt. I updated the code to remove the redundant call to session.Store. I believe the issue is with the .Load call. Remove the string.format and just pass in the temp. The document should load for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the manual formating of your id string.  That is unnecessary, and is likely wrong because of your pluralization form.

1. Name your entities in the singular.  `ExampleUser`
2. Make sure you got a result from your query. If the index is stale or the username was not found, `time` will be null.  You should check to avoid a `NullReferenceException`.
3. Just load the entity directly.  If you are using string ids, you have the full document key. If you are using integer or guid ids, Raven has an overload to convert it for you.

   var data = session.Load(time.Id);

It should just work.